# jQuery one click, but in certain cases multiple executions

Tags: javascript, jquery

File `index.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];?>/javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$( document ).on( 'click', '#txt_my_invoices', function() {
$.post("_my_invoices.php", function(data_my_invoices) {
$('#span_info').html(data_my_invoices);
});

});

});
</script>

<span id="txt_my_invoices" style="cursor:pointer; border:solid 1px grey;">My invoices</span>

<span id="span_info"></span>
```

File `_my_invoices.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$( document ).on( 'click', '.edit_invoice', function() {
alert( this.id + ' edit invoce' );
});

});
</script>


<button class="edit_invoice" id="1e" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

If open/reload file `index.php` and click on `id="txt_my_invoices"`, then see button `Click Me!`. Click on the button and one time get `alert( this.id + ' edit invoce' );`. 
But if i again click on `id="txt_my_invoices"` and click on button, then 2 times alert. Next click on `id="txt_my_invoices"` and click on button, 3 times alert and so on.

How to get only one alert (execution)?

Tried to use `.unbind()` and `.off()`, but it is no ok, because can not execute other functions.

Comment: Can you put a jsfiddle stating the use case

Comment: I could create. But there is call to external php file. As i understand jsfiddle would not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $( document ).on( 'click', '.edit_invoice', function() {
    alert( this.id + ' edit invoce' );
    });

    });
    </script>
```

This is coming again and again from your script, which causes multiple event handlers on your page.

As i understand, you want to control the button and its behavior from external script.

Can you try something similar to below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var handler = function() {
    alert( this.id + ' edit invoce' );
  };
  $( ".edit_invoice" ).unbind( "click", handler);
  $( ".edit_invoice" ).bind( "click", handler);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, need to place all jquery in `index.php`. But i need to think. For example, from `index.php` get list of invoices. If i want to copy invoice, i click on copy, go to external php, copy mysql and then i want to reload the list of invoices to see the copied invoice. That is because i placed jquery also in the second file `_my_invoices.php`. Need to think